# How to fasten main cable to BR-CT91 (Shimano Altus) brake?

Tags: rim-brake

Basic question, but it isn't addressed in instruction manual that came with the brake.

In picture, (from left to right), there is the brake, a bracket, a rubber washer and a nut.  Where do I a thread the cable through?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cable is threaded underneath the L-shaped bracket, in the corner of the L. The cable is clamped between the bracket and brake body.

You may see a shallow slot for the cable in the bracket at that point.